# Подсвечивание слов в тексте

Tags: c#

Имеется ListBox c текстом. Как сделать так, чтоб когда пишем слово в TextBox, в ListBox'e подсвечивались эти слова?

Comment: оборачивать хтмл-тегами?

Comment: А проще решение имеется!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробую отыграться :)

Мой вариант с ListView:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Test_Project
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public List<Char> letters = Enumerable.Range('a', 'z' - 'a' + 1).Select(i => (Char)i).ToList();
        public List<String> words = new List<string>();
        Random random = new Random();
        String word;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            getRandomWords();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ListViewItem item = listView1.FindItemWithText(textBox1.Text);
            int index = listView1.Items.IndexOf(item);

            if (index != -1)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
                    listView1.Items[i].BackColor = Color.White;

                listView1.Items[index].BackColor = Color.Crimson;
            }
            else
                for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
                    listView1.Items[i].BackColor = Color.White;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            getRandomWords();
        }

        protected void getRandomWords()
        {
            listView1.Items.Clear();
            words.Clear();
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                word = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                {
                    word += letters[random.Next(0, letters.Count)].ToString();
                }
                words.Add(word);
            }
            foreach (var i in words)
            {
                listView1.Items.Add(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Осталось немного мусора от старой программы, объясню вкратце:
На форме есть ListView, TextBox и есть кнопка. При запуске программы/нажатии на кнопку генерятся 10 случайных слов(тупо набор букв). Далее, смотрим по заданию.

Answer (score 3):

Добавить обработчик нажатий клавиш и в нем производить установку значений ListBox в зависимости от значений TextBox

```
private void formX_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    int index = listboxX.FindString(textboxX.Text);

    if (index != -1)
        listboxX.SetSelected(index, true);
}
```

Comment: Черт, не успел написать :D Плюсую

Comment: Это  я давно сделал!!! Такой метод выделяет позицию где находится искомое слово!!А мне надо чтоб просто слово подсвечивалось!!

Comment: @IGOR, в таком случае, Вам лучше использовать не ListBox, а ListView. Тогда вы сможете подобным образом вписать свое значение, например в listView1.Items[index].BackColor. Для ListBox такое сделать тоже можно, но тогда надо перегружать listBox1_DrawItem и ставить DrawMode в OwnerDrawFixed, это сложно.